# checking mercurial changesets

Tags: build, mercurial

So I have a build server that pulls in my changes from a mercurial repo, builds to project, runs unit tests, blah blah blah

well after I do all that I want to check the change sets that have been pulled in and update a server somewhere with the commit messages.

Can I get the changesets that mercurial has brought in for that build AFTER the pull has happened IE pull->build->get changesets, or do I have to do a hook on changegroup, save those change set commits somewhere do the build then do what I want with the commits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get them after pulling.  You need to somehow save what revision you were at before pulling.  That could be as simple as:

```
BEFORE = $(hg id --id)
.... your script here ...
CHANGES = $(hg log ${BEFORE}::.)
```